# Raycaster select the nearest objects

Tags: reactjs, three.js, raycasting, react-three-fiber

what i want is ,when the cursor is near to the particles console the particles name. but now when i hover on a particle it console its name. i need it when the cursor is near to the particle

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
      const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
      mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
      const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
      const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(particles,true);
      if (intersects.length > 0) {
        const nearestParticle = intersects[0].object;
        console.log(nearestParticle);
      }
    });
```